# How Should I skip Rows in Pandas DataFrame, that are above the Index Columns name?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to set all column names at one line. How should I do it?
I tried many things but couldn't do it, including renaming columns.

[image]

Comment: Or `droplevel` of you rather want to remove one level

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten your multiindex column header.

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Or using f-string with list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' if j else f'{i}' for i, j in df.columns]
```